# What is an OpenGL RBO?

Tags: opengl

I just read the [following](http://graphics.im.ntu.edu.tw/~vincent/resource/gpgpu/GPGPU_Programming.pdf) presentation which seemed to recommend RBOs over PBOs for GPU->CPU transfers. I have been looking for some source explaining RBOs, without success.

Anyone know of a good source explaining RBOs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From opengl wiki:

> Renderbuffer Objects are OpenGL
>   Objects that contain images. They are
>   created and used specifically with
>   Framebuffer Objects. They are
>   optimized for being used as render
>   targets, while Textures may not be.

more information [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object)

An example on gamedev.net [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_//feature/fprogramming/opengl-frame-buffer-object-101-r2331) (have a look at "Adding a Depth Buffer" section)

**EDIT**

When you render to a frame buffer you can choose between two types of framebuffer-attachable images; texture images and renderbuffer images. In the former case you will render to texture the frame buffer, in the latter you will obtain an offscreen rendering.

[Here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=292443) is a discussion on the difference between this two kind of frambuffer-attachable images.

[Here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) you can find more information about FBO and attachable images.

Comment: Why does that tutorial only use RBO only for the depth buffer, and not also the colors?

Comment: @ronag Perhaps you've already figured this out by now, and I'm only learning this stuff myself, so take this with a grain of salt: rendering the colors to a texture lets them use the resulting image as a texture. They don't need the depth info in their texture, though, so a renderbuffer is used there. Textures have more features, but renderbuffers (may) have better performance.